# Notes within Spotify collaborative playlists

Tags: spotify, libspotify

I'd like to allow Spotify users to post a small note along with a song when they post in a collaborative playlist. Is this possible with a Spotify app, or will I have to implement something else? Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+1 for the feature idea, but I don't believe it's possible with the current system. You could maintain your own database of comments linked to the playlist and track ids and display it in a Spotify app.